# error: package com.android.annotations does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following class

```
import com.android.annotations.NonNullByDefault;

@NonNullByDefault
public final class Log {
    ...
}
```

and here is my build.gradle file (some parts omitted)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.2"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

dependencies {    
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
}
```

In Android Studio there is no warning raised for my class

[image]

However when I try to build and run my app I get this error from gradle

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
Warning:[options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/home/puter/git-repos/TaskManager3/app/src/main/java/com/treemetrics/taskmanager3/util/Log.java
Error:(3, 31) error: package com.android.annotations does not exist
Error:(7, 2) error: cannot find symbol class NonNullByDefault
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.021 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: I am not migrated to X. Also the RN version 9s 0.59.9. Facing the same issue

Comment: IF USING GLIDE / FIREBASE:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57863454/294884

Answer (score 188):

To automatically fix all android to androidx issues for React Native (prerequisite npx)

Add the following two flags to `true` in your `gradle.properties` file at `ProjectFolder/android/gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Execute

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
npx react-native run-android
```

In your package.json add the following to scripts

```
  "postinstall" : "npx jetify"
```

More info at https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier

**Update:**  This is now in-built in react-native 0.60. If you migrate to react-native 0.60 you won't need this step. - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#androidx-support

Comment: I am using RN 0.59.9. Shall I use Jettifier and Android X. But I not need to migrate AndroidX. Why it getting issue with this?

Comment: @sejn everybody has to upgrade to androidX. You can read more info here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Why does one need to install jetifier as a dev dependency?

Answer (score 44):

Use implementation `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2` in gradle and then

change `import android.support.annotation.Nullable;`
 to `import androidx.annotation.NonNull;` in the classes imports

Comment: ok i have more than 100 imports in different file of library, what to do ?

Comment: @RajnishCoder use jetifier which does it for you.

Comment: Is it necessary to change Nullable to NonNull, or is it just a typo?

Answer (score 21):

Open `gradle.properties` and use following code:

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

or U can use these dependencies too:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
 implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
```

Comment: tried to add them under dependencies, but getting > Could not find method compile() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: also tried implementation instead of compile, same error

Answer (score 17):

In my case I had to use

```
import androidx.annotation...
```

instead of

```
import android.annotation...
```

I migrated to AndroidX and forgot to change that.

Answer (score 16):

I had similar issues when migrating to androidx.

If by adding the below two lines to gradle.properties did not solve the issue

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Then try

1. With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**  from the menu bar ([developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate))

If you still run into issues with migration then manually try to replace the libraries which are causing the issue.

**For example**

If you have an issue with `android.support.annotation.NonNull` change it to `androidx.annotation.NonNull` as indicated in the below class mappings table.

[Class Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)

[Maven Artifact Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)

Comment: Both refactoring and changing from `import android.support.annotation.NonNull;` to `import androidx.annotation.NonNull;` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks you. The links to the Class and Artifact Mappings were what I have been searching for for ages.

Answer (score 9):

For Ionic, try this:

```js
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

The error comes because this app is not using androidX but these plugins solve errors.

Comment: Thanks very much for Ionic answer. I was stuck with this for last couple of months

Answer (score 6):

just install(it automatically fix)

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier <--------avoid if aleardy installed start from below lines
npx jetify
```

then run

```
npx cap sync
```

finally

```
  npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 3):

Annotations come from the `support's library` which are packaged in `android.support.annotation`.

As another option you can use `@NonNull` annotation which denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can never be null.
It is imported from `import android.support.annotation.NonNull;`

Comment: I changed `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'` to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'` in my build.gradle and the import still reads `import com.android.annotations.NonNullByDefault;` and the error still occurs. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: By the way, these are automatic imports being resolved by Android Studio.

Comment: If the imports are resolved correctly then the error should not have thrown.

Comment: That's my point, why is Android Studio resolving the import like this and not underlining the import in red, but gradle is throwing an error?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't edit any code manually **jetify** should do this job for you, if you are running/building from cli using `react-native` you dont' need to do anything but if you are running/building Andriod studio you need to run **jetify** as pre-build, here is how can you automate this:

1- From the above menu go to edit configurations:

[image]

2- Add the bottom of the screen you will find **before launch** click on the plus and choose **Run External Tool**

[image]

2- Fill the following information, note that the working directory is your project root directory (not the android directory):

[image]

3- Make sure this run before anything else, in the end, your configuration should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you run this command from the command line “npx jetify” in the Android project root directory

Comment: Yeah, I did that on the root level. For some reason, I had to run npm jetify manually in order to run the app properly. For the same directory, the android studio was throwing can't run npx jetify error on the directory. even though it was the project root repo. Thanks for your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues when migrating to androidx. this issue comes due to the Old Butter Knife library dependency.

if you are using butter knife then you should use at least butter knife version  9.0.0-SNAPSHOT or above.

`implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'`

Answer (score 2):

You can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/package-summary.html) the official javadoc of the `support-annotations`library.

> Error:(3, 31) error: package com.android.annotations does not exist

As you can see all the classes are in the same package **`android.support.annotation`** and not `com.android.annotations`.

> Error:(7, 2) error: cannot find symbol class NonNullByDefault

Also the class `NonNullByDefault` **doesn't exist** in that package.

Comment: Android Studio is automatically resolving the import for me, so it's coming from somwhere, but now I am not sure where. It is also still a mystery as to why the error is being thrown.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I change the import and android automatically replaces it. Causing issues because it needs to be androidx but puts android.support imports.

Answer (score 2):

if error from butterknife auto generated file
then update butterknife dependency version

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to replace 'import android.support.annotation.Nullable' in class imports to 'import androidx.annotation.Nullable;'

Thats a common practice..whenever any import giving issue...remove that import and simply press Alt+Enter on the related class..that will give you option to 'import class'..hint Enter and things will get resolved...

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an old version of `npm`.

Run `npm install npm@latest -g` and then `npm install`