# Support Annotation does not exist after upgrading to Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-studio-3.0, gradle-android-test-plugi

After I upgrade my project to AndroidStudio 3.0-beta1, my `androidTest` files stopped compiling.

A lot of packages are not found, some of them are:

> error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   error: cannot find symbol class StringRes
>   error: cannot access AppCompatActivity
>   class file for android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity not found

I already added

```
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1"
```

into *build.gradle*

But even with this, I have the errors of package not found. I tried running the tests from inside Android Studio and from terminal with `./gradlew connectedCheck`

Comment: Besides adding the dependency explicitely for `androidTest` also need to `exclude` the `support-annotations` for those dependencies which introduce it as a transitive dependency. You can use the [GradleView plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7150-gradle-view) to find out which of your dependencies depends on `support-annotations`. Otherwise one of the libraries might raise your `support-annotations` version.

Comment: Updating butterknife to latest version solved my problem

Comment: In my case after I migrated to androidX I got this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. The issue is not that you upgraded AndroidStudio but that your target version and compile version are below 26 after updating the build tools in your SDK.

So changing

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}
```

to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
}
```

solves the issue.

Comment: both target version and compile version are at 26 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It is about the annotation support package

Comment: @Godwin try `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'`

Comment: This is not the root cause.

Answer (score 10):

Just add this to your dependencies

```html
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks Fattie! I really appreciate

Answer (score 2):

In my case it happened after migrating to androidX . 
The decision merely  was :

go to the *.java file(s) pointed and comment strings  with packages

```
 //import android.???
```

and re-import androidX-ed ones.

Build the project again and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had got similar errors and corrected it by adding.

`LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v4`
inside your Android.mk folder.

**Note**: This is for change in binary directly where you have to run .mk file separately.
If using Android Studio, check [Writing Android.mk file in Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833530/how-to-use-my-own-android-mk-file-with-android-sudio).
I read the previous answer and wanted to provide a different approach to correct it although its harder this way.