# "package android.support.annotation does not exist" after androidX migration and react-native upgrade to 0.60.4

Tags: android, react-native, android-appcompat, androidx

I have migrated to androidX using Refactor-> Migrate to AndroidX from Android Studio.

And I have upgraded my react native to 0.60.4

There after I am getting this error while building the app.

```
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

I found this solution,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56206103/9724247

It works too!

But these are coming from node modules, and I have too many errors like this.

Is there any way to handle these, other than manual edit ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the instructions at https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier/blob/master/README.md to use jetifier.

Here is the summary from the readme:

```
1. First, use Android Studio's refactoring tool to convert your app re: the Android developer docs
2. npm install --save-dev jetifier
3. npx jetify
4. npx react-native run-android (your app should correctly compile and work)
5. Call npx jetify run in the postinstall target of your package.json (Any time your dependencies update you have to jetify again)
```