# Why cannot compile Android App with JDK11?

Tags: android

I have setup an empty Basic Activity in Android Studio and I have set the following

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

but it seems that the android jar packages are not seen when building

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
error: package android.annotation does not exist
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Intent;
...
```

and many other packages from the android.jar file are not seen

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956457/7704650)

Comment: Didn't work as there are dependencies using the androidx.* package so the compiler errors and says I have to enable it back

`Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
  The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.4, androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:2.0.4
`

Comment: for `androidX` problem [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) could be helpfull

Comment: This is not an issue with androidX. All the packages from android.jar are not seen when trying to compile with jdk11 I believe due to the new introduced modularity in jdk9. Try to create new project with an empty activity and try to compile with jdk11 ... And you will get a lot of errors saying that android.* Could not be found

Comment: @Ciccio did you find out how to fix the issue? I'm experiencing the same problem